# HTML and CSS: making a button as wide as its parent paragraph

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML page with some CSS code. I am trying to make a button as wide as its parent paragraph.

The problem is that the right side of the button is not displayed correctly. I should see 1px of yellow background on the left and right side of the button. At the moment I cannot see that yellow pixel on the right side. The left side looks OK.

My browser is Mozilla Firefox 51.0.1 32-bit.

```html
<p style="width:200px; background-color:yellow">
<button style="box-sizing: border-box;
  height:24px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
  padding-left:6px;
  padding-right:6px;
  padding-top:1px;
  padding-bottom:3px;
  border:none;
  margin:1px;
  background-color:#323B5A;
  font-size:11px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-decoration:none;
  line-height:18px;
  border-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  display:block;
  width:100%;">OK</button>
</p>
```

Comment: Remove `margin: 1px` and add `pading: 0 1px` on `p`.

Comment: Have you tried `width: 98%; margin: auto;` on the `button` element?

Comment: Removing `margin: 1px;` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have following styles on button:

```
button {
  margin: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

So `width: 100%` + `margin: 1px` extending `button`'s width a bit more than `100%` i.e `100% + 2px` actually.

To fix this, you can:

1. Remove `margin: 1px` from `button`.
2. Add left / right indents (`padding`) on `p`.

```html
<p style="width:200px; background-color:yellow; padding: 0 1px;">
<button style="box-sizing: border-box;
  height:24px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
  padding-left:6px;
  padding-right:6px;
  padding-top:1px;
  padding-bottom:3px;
  border:none;
  background-color:#323B5A;
  font-size:11px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-decoration:none;
  line-height:18px;
  border-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  display:block;
  width:100%;">OK</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The margin is not being taken into account for the width. You can change the width of the button in the inline CSS to:

```
width: calc(100% - 2px);
```

Where 2px is the total size of your margin and it will work.

```html
<p style="width:200px; background-color:yellow">
<button style="box-sizing: border-box;
  height:24px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
  padding-left:6px;
  padding-right:6px;
  padding-top:1px;
  padding-bottom:3px;
  border:none;
  margin:1px;
  background-color:#323B5A;
  font-size:11px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-decoration:none;
  line-height:18px;
  border-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  display:block;
  width:calc(100% - 2px);">OK</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the margin isn't being taken into consideration when the browser calculates the width.

```html
<p style="width:200px; background-color:yellow">
<button style="box-sizing: border-box;
  height:24px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
  padding-left:6px;
  padding-right:6px;
  padding-top:1px;
  padding-bottom:3px;
  border:none;
  margin:1px;
  background-color:#323B5A;
  font-size:11px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-decoration:none;
  line-height:18px;
  border-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  display:block;
  width:calc(100% - 2px);">OK</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin: auto; width: calc(100% - 2px);` and then all you have to adjust is `2px` for the background border color to appear on either side at whatever width you want it.

```html
<p style="width:200px; background-color:yellow">
<button style="box-sizing: border-box;
  height:24px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
  padding-left:6px;
  padding-right:6px;
  padding-top:1px;
  padding-bottom:3px;
  border:none;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:#323B5A;
  font-size:11px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-decoration:none;
  line-height:18px;
  border-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  display:block;
  width:calc(100% - 2px);">OK</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout my code snippet: https://codepen.io/imcodingideas/pen/oexLyw

I removed some `padding`, and other properties in favor of `flexbox`.

```
p {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow
}

button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #323B5A;
  line-height: 18px;
  height: 24px;
  border: none;
  margin: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the box model. https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

One way would be to use calc, but the other way would be to adjust your thinking site-wide so that padding and borders move *in* the box instead of being added to the outside like you've done on your button.

You probably shouldn't put a button in your paragraph though.

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements, but allowing components to change */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

```
<section class="stuff">

  <p>
    <button class='my-button'>
      <span>My Button</span>
    </button>
  </p>

</section>
```

or

```
<section class="stuff">

  <p>
    words
  </p>

  <button class='my-button'>
    <span>My Button</span>
  </button>

</section>
```

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

section.stuff {
  max-width: 200px;
}

section.stuff p {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.my-button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/j6sqafqp/

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
button {
width: 100%;
}
```